# Combine 2 sql query in to 1 query

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 queries which retrieve records from same table. I want all the result in one table.

1st query

```
SELECT ID, NAME, FKNGRP
  FROM EMPINFO      
 WHERE ID = ‘03’
   AND SERIALNO =  ‘N’
   AND (FKNGRP  = 1001 OR FKNGRP = 1002 )
```

2nd query

```
SELECT ID, NAME, FKNGRP
  FROM EMPINFO      
 WHERE ID = ‘04’
   AND SERIALNO =  ‘N’
   AND (FKNGRP  = 1001 OR FKNGRP = 1005 OR FKNGRP = 1009  )
```

I want to combine these 2 queries and get the result in DB2.

Comment: Homework question? (just curious)

Comment: Add the word UNION or UNION ALL between the two statements

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID, NAME, FKNGRP
FROM EMPINFO      
WHERE 
(
   ID = ‘04’
   and SERIALNO =  ‘N’
   AND FKNGRP in (1001, 1005, 1009)
)
or
(
   ID = ‘03’
   and SERIALNO =  ‘N’
   AND FKNGRP in (1001, 1002)
)
```